# Detect touch on uiview under the UIButton when button is pressed

Tags: iphone, events, uiview, uibutton, touch

i am using a uiview parent view....overidded touch began and touch ended methods...
when i added a UIButton as a subview in the view and touch on the button touchdown event is detected and associated method is called ...but touchbegan method that was over ridden is not called...

what i want is when i touch the button the method associated with the touchdown event and touchBegan method of uiview both be called simultaneously...UIbutton is not passing the touch to its superview i.e. uiview.....?
Any idea how to do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how to call two `touchesBegan` events simultaneously on two different views, but you probably want to override the `hitTest:withEvent:` method of `UIView`. This will allow you to catch a touch event on the view *underneath* the `UIButton` *before* it gets to the button (hitTests work from the `window` upwards to the foremost view).

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (passToSubviews)
    {
        return [super hitTest: point withEvent: event];
    }

    // otherwise stop the subview receiving touches
    if ([super hitTest: point withEvent: event])
    {
        return self;
    }

    return nil;     
}
```

Maybe this can help...

EDIT:

Just a guess but you could try:

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView* hitSubview = [super hitTest: point withEvent: event];
    if (hitSubview)
    {
         [self doTouchedInStuff];
         return hitSubview;
    }

    return self;         
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self doTouchedInStuff];

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: passToSubview ? just overriding this method will make the difference ?

Comment: Yes this will allow you to define where the touches are detected- but not to detect touches on 2 different views at the same time